# From a list of data gather only the 7 desired items and create a new list of lists removing unwanted data?

Tags: python, database, list, for-loop, iteration

I need to iterate over a list, check if that item is an `integer` with `< 3` digits, if not, skip that item and go to the next. Do this until it finds the correct item. Then grab that item, and the following 6, for a total of 7 items yielding groups of 7 in a new list of lists. This would allow me to skip over `'some struff I don't want'` and only grab the correct grouped 7 items I do want out of the data even if there are a random set of strings in between.

I've tried to use a for loop:

```
for x in vendor:
    if x in vendor == len(int[0:]) < 3:
        vendor = [vendor[x:x+7] for x in range(0, len(vendor), 7)]
    else:
        pass
```

But this just gets me a TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable. The error makes sense, but I'm at a loss for how to get this done. Here's an idea for what I need my output to be from the input data.

Data:

```
['1','1','2', '11" Some Words symbols and numbers mixed 3-4-2#', '4', '3.00', '43.00 NC', '1','1','2', '11" Some Words symbols and numbers mixed 3-4-2#', '3.00', '3','43.00 NC', 'some stuff I dont want', '1','1','2', '11" Some Words symbols and numbers mixed 3-4-2#', '3.00', '3', '43.00 NC']
```

Output:

```
[['1','1','2', '11" Some Words symbols and numbers mixed 3-4-2#', '4', '3.00', '43.00 NC'], ['1','1','2', '11" Some Words symbols and numbers mixed 3-4-2#', '3.00', '3', '43.00 NC'], ['1','1','2', '11" Some Words symbols and numbers mixed 3-4-2#', '3.00', '3', '43.00 NC']]
```

The data sets are structured, but every once in a while there is an extra item that isn't needed and there's no way to tell what that random item will be, or when it will occur.

Comment: can you provide a little more explanation or better example for the transition of input to output? from one look it looks you are making sublist containing 6 elements only.

Comment: int is  type in python so avoid using that variable name.

Comment: To be clear, you want to *search* through the input list for sub-sequences of 7 items, where the first three meet the criteria? And what is this "3 or less than 6" business?

Comment: It might help to explain where the data comes from, and why it contains the extra items you want to skip.

Comment: The items come from text data taken from PDF. I edited my question to make more sense. I am very new to this so I apologize for my poor english. It was meant to say "3 or less digits" meaning less less than '123'. There may be a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, but I am new so do not know all the ways to do things yet. Hence the question. If I already knew how to word everything and put in proper syntax I wouldn't need to ask the question would I?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This worked to put only the 7 elements into the sublists that I wanted and skipped over any random list items that made it into the initial list. It worked perfectly for what I needed to do.

```
items = []
i = 0
while i < len(data):
    try:
        if int(data[i]) < 100:
            items.append(data[i:i+7])
            i += 7
    except ValueError:
        i += 1
```